Compose Navigation Animation not working with latest navigation compose library 2.8.0-beta02
I was using slide animations for navigating between screens in Jetpack Compose Navigation using string-based route navigation and everything was working fine. But now I have upgraded the navigation library to the latest beta:
navigationComposeVersion = "2.8.0-beta02"

Now the problem is ever since I upgraded the navigation system from String route-based to the latest, the transition animations have not worked. It is now like some fast slide animation exists when moving from A -> B (expected behaviour is slow slide animation). But when popping back there is no animation. Here is my code:
SlideComposable.kt
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentScope
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentTransitionScope
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry
import androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable

/**
 * Constant for the duration of the slide animation.
 */
const val SlideAnimationDuration = 500

/**
 * Extension function for [NavGraphBuilder] to create a composable with slide animations for a specific [BaseScreen] subclass.
 *
 * @param content The composable content block with [AnimatedContentScope] and [NavBackStackEntry].
 */
inline fun <reified T : BaseScreen> NavGraphBuilder.slideComposable(
    noinline content: @Composable (AnimatedContentScope.(NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit),
) {
    composable<T>(
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                animationSpec = tween(SlideAnimationDuration),
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                animationSpec = tween(SlideAnimationDuration),
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                animationSpec = tween(SlideAnimationDuration),
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                animationSpec = tween(SlideAnimationDuration),
            )
        },
        content = content,
    )
}

SearchNavGraph.kt
import androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder
import androidx.navigation.toRoute
import com.xxx.android.xxxserch.presentation.listingdetails.screen.ListingDetailsScreen
import com.xxx.android.xxxserch.presentation.search.screen.SearchScreen
import com.xxx.android.foundation.navigation.Screen
import com.xxx.android.foundation.navigation.navigationmanagers.HomeNavigationManager
import com.xxx.android.presentation.appstate.XXXAppState
import com.commonlibs.android.foundation.navigation.customcomponents.slideComposable

fun NavGraphBuilder.searchNavGraph(appState: XXXAppState) {
    val homeNavigationManager = HomeNavigationManager(appState)
    slideComposable<Screen.SearchScreen> {
        val searchScreen = it.toRoute<Screen.SearchScreen>()
        SearchScreen(
            loadLocationsScreen = { homeNavigationManager.gotoLocationsScreen() },
            loadFilterScreen = homeNavigationManager.gotoFilterScreen,
            searchText = searchScreen.searchKeyword,
            backToPrevScreen = homeNavigationManager.backToPrevScreen,
            loadHomeDetailsScreen = homeNavigationManager.gotoHomeDetailScreen,
        )
    }
    slideComposable<Screen.ListingDetailScreen> {
        val listingDetailsScreen = it.toRoute<Screen.ListingDetailScreen>()
        ListingDetailsScreen(
            homeId = listingDetailsScreen.homeId,
            backToPreviousScreen = homeNavigationManager.backToPrevScreen,
        )
    }
}

HomeNavGraph.kt
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeNavGraph(appState: XXXAppState) {
    val homeNavigationManager = HomeNavigationManager(appState)
    slideComposable<BottomNavItem.Home> {
        HomeScreen(
            loadLocationsScreen = { homeNavigationManager.gotoLocationsScreen() },
            loadFilterScreen = homeNavigationManager.gotoFilterScreen,
            loadSearchModule = homeNavigationManager.gotoSearchModule,
            loadDetailsScreen = homeNavigationManager.gotoDetailScreen,
        )
    }
    slideComposable<Screen.HomeFilterScreen> {
        HomeFilterScreen(
            goBackToPrevScreen = homeNavigationManager.backToPrevScreen,
        )
    }
}

This is the function for navigating
fun XXXAppState.navigate(screen: BaseScreen) {
    if (navController.isLifecycleResumed) {
        navController.navigate(screen) {
            launchSingleTop = true
        }
    }
}

class HomeNavigationManager(private val appState: XXXAppState) {
    val backToPrevScreen: () -> Unit = {
        appState.popUp()
    }

    val gotoFilterScreen: () -> Unit = {
        appState.navigate(Screen.HomeFilterScreen)
    }

    val gotoSearchModule: (String) -> Unit = {
        appState.navigate(Screen.SearchScreen(searchKeyword = it))
    }

    val gotoHomeDetailScreen: (String) -> Unit = {
        appState.navigate(Screen.ListingDetailScreen(it))
    }
}

Sealed class for Screens
@Serializable
sealed class Screen : BaseScreen() {
    @Serializable
    data object HomeFilterScreen : Screen()

    @Serializable
    data class SearchScreen(val searchKeyword: String) : Screen()

    @Serializable
    data class ListingDetailScreen(val careHomeId: String) : Screen()
}


Navigation 2.8.0-beta02 depends on Compose 1.7.0-beta02 (which is actually what is controlling how your animations run) - do you see the same animation problem if you keep your old version of Navigation, but upgrade your Compose version?

Ok. I'll try with Compose beta. Animations stopped working after I implemented latest version. Anims are working fine with old version.

Okay, if just updating your Compose version breaks it while keeping the older Navigation version, then you should definitely file a bug against Compose as they would need to fix the core issue on their end. Please include a link here and I can make sure it gets to the right person :)

Sure I will do that. "Animations stopped working after I implemented latest version" I meant Navigation compose version not Compose version

Like I said in my first comment, upgrade your Compose version first (don't touch your Navigation version) and verify whether the animations still work.

Hey, were you able to solve the issue? I've updated to the latest version (type-safe) and animations are not behaving the way I want. It doesn't matter what I set.
